# problem with url rewrite .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-routing

I'm writing a mvc framework in php, and trying to rewrite urls using this pattern:

> www.example.com/contact/send/

to read as

> www.example.com/index.php?url=contact/send/

So I can explode the $_GET['url'] var and use into the fw to route.

Its working great in almost any case, the only issue is that when I try to use a string that is a folder too, ak 'admin', **without** a trailing slash, the url exposes the variables.

Like this:

> www.example.com/admin/ - OK, the url stays just like that
>
> www.example.com/admin - Heres the problem, the url redirects browser to:
>
> www.example.com/admin/?url=admin

The $_GET['url'] is set and working ok in both cases, but I wish to doesnt expose the 'url=admin'.

Theres any way to do that?

Thanks!

The .htaccess is:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
>   [PT,L]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a ! :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

You want to rewrite when it is NOT a directory.

**Edit:** Or maybe a exception

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/?
```